# Can two points always be joined by timelike curve?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, causality

I have asked this question on MSE but now I think it is better suited for the Physics Stack Exchange. Suppose $p$ and $q$ are connected by a causal (i.e. its tangent vectors have non-positive norm) curve $\gamma$. If $\gamma$ is not a null geodesic, can it be deformed into a smooth, timelike curve still connecting $p$ and $q$?

This is in Hawking and Ellis, Proposition 4.5.10. I write the proof below with as many details as I could fill in, but there are still some gaps I cannot solve.

Denote by $D_t$ the covariant derivative along $\gamma$ induced by the Levi-Civita connection
$\nabla$. We know $\gamma$ is a null geodesic if the acceleration vector $D_t \gamma '(t) = 0$ and
$\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)\rangle = 0$ everywhere. Thus, if $\gamma$ is not a null geodesic,
there must exist a point $t_0$ where $D_t\gamma'(t_0) \neq 0$ or where
$\langle \gamma'(t_0), \gamma'(t_0) \rangle < 0$. By continuity, if either of these cases hold, then
they hold on an open interval $I = (t_1, t_2)$. However, if $\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle < 0$ on $I$
then $\gamma$ is already timelike, so there is nothing to prove. Consequently, we assume that $D_t
\gamma' \neq 0$ on $I$. Here it is claimed in the book that
$$
\langle D_t \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle = \frac 12 \partial_t \langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle = 0,
$$
but I cannot see why this is so. Can we reparametrize any causal curve so its velocity has constant norm even it at some points the curve becomes null? Taking this for granted, we deduce that $D_t \gamma'$ is spacelike and thus $a(t) ^2 := \langle D_t \gamma'(t), D_t \gamma'(t)\rangle > 0$
on $I$.

We can Fermi transport a vector with positive inner product against $\gamma'$ to obtain a vector
field $W$ along $\gamma|_I$ s.t. $c(t) := -\langle W, \gamma'(t)\rangle > 0$ on $I$ and generate the variation
$$ \Gamma(s, t) = \exp_{\gamma(t)}(s (x W + y D_t \gamma'(t))), \quad S = \partial_s \Gamma(s, t),
\quad T = \partial_t \Gamma(s, t)
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are functions to be chosen momentarily but keeping in mind the requirement that $x(t_1) =
x(t_2) = y(t_1) = y(t_2) = 0$ to ensure $\Gamma_s(t_1) = \gamma(t_1)$ and $\Gamma_s(t_2)
= \gamma(t_2)$. Then, $\Gamma_s(t)$ will be timelike if $\langle T, T \rangle < 0$ everywhere, which
would hold if the the derivative with respect to $s$ at $s = 0$ were negative:

\begin{align}
  - 1 &= \frac{1}{2} \partial_s|_0 \langle T, T \rangle = \langle D_s T, T \rangle
  \\
      &= \langle D_t S, T \rangle & \nabla \text{ is torsion free,}
  \\
      &= \partial_t \langle S, T \rangle - \langle S, D_t T\rangle & \text{metric compatibility,}
  \\
  &= \partial_t (x \langle W, \gamma' \rangle) - x \langle W, D_t \gamma'\rangle - y \langle D_t \gamma', D_t \gamma'
    \rangle & T|_{s = 0} = \gamma',
  \\
  &= u' + \langle W, D_t \gamma'\rangle c ^{-1} u - y a(t) ^2 & \text{Letting } u = - x c.
\end{align}
With the integrating factor $b(t) = -\int_{t_1} ^t \langle W, D_t \gamma'(s) \rangle c(s) ^{-1}
\mathrm{d} s$ we have
\begin{align}
(u e ^{-b})' e ^{b} = y a(t) ^2 - 1 &\Rightarrow u = e ^b \int_{t_1} ^t e ^{-b(s)} (y(s) a(s) ^2 - 1)
                      \mathrm{d} s
  \\
  &\Rightarrow x = c(t) ^{-1}e ^{b(t)} \int_{t_1} ^t e ^{-b(s)} (1 - y(s) a(s) ^2)
                      \mathrm{d} s.
\end{align}
To satisfy our earlier constraints, we could let $y$ be a parabola with roots ata $t_1$ and
$t_2$. By scaling and applying the intermediate value theorem, we could find an appropriate factor
s.t.
$$ \int_{t_1} ^{t_2} e ^{-b(s)}(1 - y(s) a(s) ^2) \mathrm{d} s = 0$$
because $a(s)$ does not vanish. However, in the book, they instead define
$$
x = c^{-1} e ^b \int_{t_1}^t e^{-b}(1 - a^2 y/2) \text d s
$$
and I do not understand where this extra factor of a half is coming from. I think I may be misunderstanding the proof. Could someone point me in the right direction?